# Populate divs with same id with content from textareas of same id that is stored in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code below, i want to get the content of the textareas with the same id of each table row and store it in an array. When I get them I want to append each of them in a div with the same id on a different table. I tried but it appends only the first content to all the divs.
For example instead of web updates and ssl certificates on each row of column description it displays web updates on both of them.

```
<table id="items">
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Unit Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item-row">
    <td class="description">
      <textarea id='description'>Monthly web updates</textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea id='cost'class="cost">€650.00</textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item-row">
    <td class="description">
      <textarea id='description'> SSL certificates </textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea id='cost'class="cost">€75.00</textarea>
    </td>     
  </tr>  
</table>
```

The result should look like the same table but instead of textareas it should have div with `<p> </p>` inside.

Comment: Please include what have you tried so far.  Looks like you are using the same `id=` twice, which is not valid HTML.

Comment: id can't be used twice in the same document. Use classes instead. And no, you can't just make it happen that it works with two id's that are the same.

Comment: what is bothering you in the principle that an identifier must be unique?

Comment: you can't use ids twice, use classes instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially you only can use one unique id for each element with id attribute. That is why you can't select more than one element by id

```
let single = document.getElementById('id');
let multiple = document.getElementsByTagName('tag');
```